# Usar Etiqueta <a> como un contenedor

Tags: html, html5, web, estándares

Buen día, estoy haciendo un ejercicio con HTML y me ha surgido una duda, estoy encerrando en una etiqueta `<a>` un `<div>`y dentro de este mismo hay una etiqueta `<p>` y otra `<img>` y pues funciona bien y como quiero, mi consulta es, ¿Es correcto hacerlo así según los estándares web?

```html
<a href="enlace">
 <div>
  <p>texto</p>
  <img src="img.png">
 </div>
</a>
```

Comment: Depende de la versión de HTML que uses:

Answer (score 3):

Depende de la versión de HTML que uses se considerara correcto o no:

- En [HTML5](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/text-level-semantics.html#the-a-element): se permite tener casi cualquier tipo de contenido dentro de una etiqueta `a`: elementos de bloque o inline, mientras que no sean elementos interactivos (p.e. otros enlaces o botones). Por lo que sí es correcto tener un `div`, `p` o `img` dentro del `a`.
- En [versiones anteriores de HTML](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/links.html#edef-A): no estaría permitido tener un `div` dentro de un `a` porque solo se podrían tener elementos inline (y `div` es un elemento de bloque) para excluyendo elementos interactivos como otros `a`. Así en el caso que expones no se permitirían `div` o `p` pero sí `img` porque es inline.

Fuente/Bibliografía:

- [Respuesta de NickFitz en StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1828032)
- [Artículo de MDN sobre `a`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Elemento/a)

Comment: Respuesta un poco más detallada (inglés): [Is putting a div inside an anchor ever correct?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1828032/4565367). Creo que es bueno citar las fuentes.

Comment: @FranciscoRomero debo reconocer que usé esa respuesta para obtener los enlaces en una de las ediciones que hice de mi respuesta. Pero fue una vez escrita. Mi respuesta no es una copia o una traducción de esa. Me tomo muy en serio el tema del plagio en el sitio (y fuera de él) y cuando he escrito una pregunta basada/traducida de otra, lo he hecho citando la fuente original.

Comment: Yo la verdad que a esa respuesta ya había llegado otras veces y cuando he leído la tuya me ha venido una imagen de esa respuesta. Si te fijas, la estructura y el contenido es muy parecido (aunque no igual). No iba con ninguna mala intención, solo era un apunte sobre la fuente de la que estaba casi seguro que provenía por sus similitudes. Ahora veo que las has nombrado, me alegra ver eso :)